# How to get the HTTP verb inside a JsonMediaTypeFormatter / MediaTypeFormatter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, json.net

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the current HTTP verb from the request inside a JsonMediaTypeFormatter or MediaTypeFormatter? I built a formatter that sanitizes input strings in JSON PUT & POST requests, however I don't seem to have access to the http context inside the ReadFromStreamAsync event. I'd hate to have to parse all objects on a GET request as that will kill performance.

I am using the Json.Net implementation in .net 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facepalm. `HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod` solves my problem.